# Re-usable UITableView "base class" with custom section header

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom table view section header (set of colored lines) that I am using in around a dozen different table views. Currently, I'm cutting and pasting the same code in every single UITableViewDelegate handler.

For example, something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width - 80, height: 1))
    lineView.backgroundColor = .separator
    headerView.addSubview(lineView)
    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}
```

Is it possible to subclass or extend UITableView in some way so that this code is written once and automatically applied to any of my specified tableviews?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you need to subclass table view delegate, not the table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `class BaseVC` and conform `UITableViewDelegate` `protocol`. Implement `viewForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` methods in it, i.e.

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width - 80, height: 1))
        lineView.backgroundColor = .separator
        headerView.addSubview(lineView)
        return headerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Now, inherit your `ViewControllers` from `BaseVC` like so,

```
class VC: BaseVC, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, however it may not work in one of my scenarios where I have 2 tableviews in a view controller and only want the section header applied to one of them? I guess I can override the delegate functions only for this edge case and it should be fine?

Comment: For that you can override heightForHeaderInSection method and return 0 for the tableView in which you don't want it.